# Batch file to unzip file contents to folder and rename / prefix contents with zip file name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, zip, rename

I regularly receive multiple .zip files via ftp.

I unzip each .zip file individually to a folder titled the name of the .zip file and rename each file in the folder with the name of the original .zip file.

Example:

If I receive a .zip file called "10 smith street windsor.zip" that contains the files "permit application.doc", "architectural drawings.doc", I unzip the contents of the .zip to a new folder called "10 smith street windsor" and prefix each file with the name of the folder i.e. "10 smith street windsor - permit application.doc", "10 smith street windsor - architectural drawings.doc".

I would like to automate this manual process with a batch file that creates a folder named for each .zip file, copies the content of the .zip file to the folder, and then renames each file in the folder with the name of the original .zip file.

My preference is to use the command line version of 7zip (7za).

I have modified an existing script I found on the web (see below) but it only works for folder names that have no spaces.  For example the script below creates a folder for the .zip file "10_smith_street_windsor.zip" and renames / prefixes the folder / zip contents successfully, but fails on a .zip file with spaces "10 smith street windsor.zip"

```
rem loop through all the zips
for %%c in (*.zip) do (`enter code here`
    rem make a temporary folder with the same name as zip to house the zip content
    if not exist %%~nc md %%~nc
    rem extract zip content into the temporary folder
    7za e -o"%%~nc" %%c
    if exist "%%~nc" (
        rem jump into the temporary folder
        pushd "%%~nc"
        if exist *.* (
            rem loop through all the files found in the temporary folder and prefix it with the zip's name
            for %%i in (*.*) do (
                ren "%%i" "%%~nc.%%i"
            )
         )
        rem jump out of the temporary folder
        popd
    )
)
```

Would love any help please :-)

Regards

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%z in (*.zip) do (
        if not exist "%%~nz" md "%%~nz"
        7za e -o"%%~nz" "%%~fz"
        for %%f in ("%%~nz\*") do ren "%%~ff" "%%~nz - %%~nxf"
    )
```

For each zip file, if a folder with the same name does not exist, create it. Extract the zip file into the new folder. For each file inside the folder, rename the file to the name of the zip followed by the original name of the file.

Comment: MC ND your answer is perfect. Thankyou so much for taking the time to respond.